# Proof that the coefficients of a polynomial are real

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

How does one prove that all the coefficients of this polynomial: $$(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}$$ are real numbers, without using Newton's Binomial Theorem?

Comment: Do you know that a polynomial $a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots+a_{10}z^{10}$ must have real coefficients if evaluations of the polynomial are real for all real numbers $z$?

Comment: @T.A.E How would one show that the polynomial above is real for every real evaluation of $x$

Comment: @Amr: By computing its imaginary component $\Im\{z\} = \frac{1}{2}(z - \bar{z})$ to be zero. Or just showing it's equal to its complex conjugate.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes and this method could just be applied directly to the polynomial in the OP,s post without have to use the fact in T.A.E's comment

Comment: @Amr, the fact in T.A.E's comment (and which is in my answer too) is in fact a very important point of the proof. The question is about _the coefficients of the polynomial to be real_, and not _the polynomial to have real values on the reals_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you agree with this:

> If $p$ is a complex polynomial such that:
>   $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\quad p(x)\in\mathbb{R}$$
>   then all the coefficients of $p$ are real

you'll find a good strategy!

Comment: Can you actually explain that why if the evaluation at all real numbers is real the polynomial has real coefficients?  Maybe it is easy but for some reason it's not clear to me.  (It seems pretty intuitive though)

Comment: @Seth If you know derivatives, you could go by a simple induction: $p(0)$ is the constant coefficient of $p$ (hence must be real), and $p'$ will satisfy that property too...

Comment: If I accept the fact what would the good strategy be ?

Comment: And why the downvote please? I actually gave the argument that's missing in the other upvoted answers–that are actually no pedagogical since don't give any enlightenment to the OP.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted your answer, and there is no reason for someone to do that.

Comment: @Amr probably the one you used in your answer, without explaining anything? (just saying).

Comment: Thanks, that was a very nice answer.  I upvoted you.

Comment: @Seth thanks! `:)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input .  
@gniourf_gniourf your solution is quite elegant , but I was looking for something blunt and simple .

Comment: @Victor keep in mind that the other answers help you show that _the polynomial takes real values on the reals_, not that _the polynomial has real coefficients_. For this, you need the fact I stated.

Comment: @Victor My answer is not as rigorous as this answer

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf exactly... I thought of the complex conjugation trick right away and then I realized I wasn't sure why it would solve the problem.  I wondered if evaluation at all real numbers are real implied the coefficients were real (since that solves the problem) and then saw this answer.  Hence my comments above.

Comment: You're right , indeed . My apologies , @gniourf_gniourf !

Answer (score 2):

Fact: A complex number $z$ is real iff $z=\overline{z}$

Fact: $z\rightarrow \overline{z}$ is a field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$

$$\overline{(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}}=\overline{(x+i)^{10}}+\overline{(x-i)^{10}}=(\overline{x+i})^{10}+(\overline{x-i})^{10}=(x-i)^{10}+(x+i)^{10}$$

Comment: And then, how do you show that _the coefficients of the polynomial are real numbers_?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Right, I deduced this after reading your first comment

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline{(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}} =\overline{x+i}^{10}+\overline{x-i}^{10}=(\overline x-i)^{10}+(\overline x+i)^{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without relying on a general theorem about complex conjugates.

Let $P(x)=(x+i)^{10}+(x-i)^{10}$ be the polynomial in question.  Let

$$Q(x)=P(ix)=(ix+i)^{10}+(ix-i)^{10}=-(x+1)^{10}-(x-1)^{10}$$

The coefficients of $Q$ are obviously real.  But also, $Q(-x)=Q(x)$, so $Q$ is an *even* function of $x$, i.e., $Q(x)=R(x^2)$ for some polynomial $R$ with real coefficients.  But this leads to

$$P(x)=Q(-ix)=R(-x^2)$$

hence the coefficients of $P$ are real (and $P$ is also an even function of $x$).